# nav2 teb 'lookup would require extrapolation into the future'

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using the dwb Controller in the ros2 nav stack for a while now with success. Today, I wanted to try out the teb local planner.

Building and loading the plugin were a breeze, but for some reason, whenever I set a goal, I get this transform error:

```
[controller_server-10] [ERROR] [1595453488.697856494] [controller_server]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1595453488.692529 but the latest data is at time 1595453488.682535, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
```

Then my robot enters a recovery state, until it hits this error again.

If I switch back to using DWB, the error is gone!.

I'm using cyclonedds as my rmw implementation on ros2 foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357836/nav2-teb-%27lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future%27/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2020-11-19**:
Did you solve the issue? And could you maybe share your configuration for the tab planner?

**Comment by [sph](https://answers.ros.org/users/41382/sph/) on 2021-03-30**:
I also had the same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF issues can be caused by so many things its really hard to generally debug for someone else without doing it myself. I will say:

- Check your odom->map publisher, make sure its publishing fast enough and slightly into the future since this leads your system
- Check your robot state publisher, make sure its publishing fast enough
- Check your outputs of RL and make sure that's fast enough

Almost all TF problems like that boil down in my experience to:

- Poorly setup custom RL configs / sensor publishing / transform update rates
- Your SLAM or localizer isn't leading the system a little bit
- You're running on a tiny tiny CPU and overloading it (disguard if i3 or better)

This is the type of things you toil with once when you set up a new robot and hopefully never touch again afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To add to the previous accurate answer, in case you use hector slam, a solution is given in this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/40541/extrapolation-error-of-local-cost-map-in-navigation/?answer=121776#post-id-121776)

**Edit:** Alternatively, @balkce suggested a solution for move_base's base_local_planner, by adding a waitForTransform [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/164911/move_base-and-extrapolation-errors-into-the-future/).

Another possible solution is to use amcl since it accepts future-dated transforms, as opposed to hector slam and gmapping

---

Originally posted by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) with karma: 233 on 2021-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2